# Bigquery Java API - Get sublisting within a cloud folder?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

How do I get a list of objects within a sub-directory on cloud storage using the Bigquery Java api?

I can get a list of objects within a folder but not within a second level folder. 
So if I have 
/Folder1/Folder2/File1.csv
/Folder1/File2.csv

I can get Folder2 & File2.csv using the following command:

```
list = cloudstorage.objects().list("Folder1");
```

But how do I get the list of objects within Folder2?

Comment: this doesn't seem like a 'bigquery' question?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa My bad, I added that I'm using the Bigquery Java API

Comment: still not bigquery, I think you want the [google-cloud-storage] tag

Comment: I think you should use setPrefix method to filter results to objects whose names begin with this prefix. and Yes, this is not BigQuery but rather Cloud Storage JSON Java API

Comment: Assuming your bucket is Folder1 i think the value to pass there - will be "Folder2/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think - you should use setPrefix method to filter results to objects whose names begin with this prefix. Assuming your bucket is Folder1, you should try

```
setPrefix("Folder2/")
```